# Trigger standard new/edit form validation from custom button code behind

Tags: validation, newform

I've got a standard new and edit form with one custom button on it. I want to trigger the usual form validation, when the button is clicked and ONLY execute the code behind the button when the form validation is true.

Is it possible to trigger the standard form validation from code behind?
(SharePoint 2010)